# Do major passenger airline jets have airbrakes/speedbrakes?

Tags: flight-controls, airbrakes

Now I've heard that passenger airliners do not generally have airbrakes , and simply use their spoilers as airbrakes since they can perform the same function.

Are there any major jets that use speedbrakes (by major I mean widely used by countries or airlines, and it must be a passenger jet)

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [For large jets, what is the primary means of slowing down after landing?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1219/65)

Comment: You understand that a spoiler is essentially a type of airbrake, right? It's just specifically one that also reduces lift.

Comment: @JonStory as you pointed out, they're not the same. Spoilers reduces lift (vertical force), thus if a pilot wishes to maintain vertical speed, AoA has to be increased. When AoA increases, drag increases. Airbrakes increases drag directly by countering the forward momentum of the aircraft. I believe that's what the OP is asking.

Comment: Airbrakes also reduce lift (vertical force) - when your aircraft slows down, it reduces lift.... the Spoiler has lift reduction as a primary function with reduction in airspeed secondary, whereas an airbrake is the reverse: the essential point remains that both reduce lift and airspeed.

Answer (score 11):

Yes (for some values of major)

[image: BAE 146]
<sup>*Adrian Pingstone*</sup>

[[image: Fokker 70]

<sup>*(c) Harm Rutten*</sup>](http://www.airliners.net/photo/KLM-Cityhopper/Fokker-70-(F-28-0070)/0503269/L/)

Comment: I am not sure if thrust reversers (2nd picture)  would count as conventional airbrakes.

Comment: @yankeekilo: redirect your gaze to the rearmost point of the Fokker 70 fuselage.

Comment: Hehe, talk of human factors... I was browsing on my smartphone on the go and only registered the reversers :D

Comment: @yankeekilo. Actually Concorde used to use its reversers as airbrakes during the descent.

Comment: @vectorVictor Very interesting! That would sure merit an answer if not for the demise of the Concorde program.